# TikZ: node positioning in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw several nodes below each other. Therefore I use relative positioning with a node alias. It seems the positions are out of alignment the more nodes are drawn. This is what I tried:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  unit/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm}
]

\draw[black!10, very thin] (0, -4) grid [step=1mm] +(4, 8);
\draw[help lines] (0, -4) grid [step=10mm] +(4, 8);
\filldraw (0,0) circle [radius=2pt];

\node[unit] (c1) at (0,3) [alias=last] {};

\foreach \i in {2,...,5}
  \node[unit] (c\i) [alias=last, below=5mm of last] {};

\filldraw[gray!50] (c3) circle [radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks (note the yellow marked spots):

[image: nodes]

I want to have the circles aligned to the grid. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include `outer sep=0pt`,

```
unit/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm, outer sep=0pt,}
```

the result are as desired.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  unit/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm, 
      outer sep=0pt,% <-- added
  }
]

\draw[black!10, very thin] (0, -4) grid [step=1mm] +(4, 8);
\draw[help lines] (0, -4) grid [step=10mm] +(4, 8);
\filldraw (0,0) circle [radius=2pt];

\node[unit] (c1) at (0,3) [alias=last] {};

\foreach \i in {2,...,5}
  \node[unit] (c\i) [alias=last, below=5mm of last] {};

\filldraw[gray!50] (c3) circle [radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

@PeterGrill [answered earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646895/73317) but I was preparing illustrations. ;-) So, here is the important thing: node anchors are placed at `outer sep` from the *middle line* of the node border.

The border middle line of your `c1` circle has its high and low points at ordinates that are multiples of 5 (starting from the origin at `(0,0)`, using `1mm` as unit length). This is an ideal circle with no thickness. When Ti*k*Z draws the border, there is ink on both sides, in equal thickness:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt, draw opacity=0.3]

\draw[black!10, very thin] (0, -4) grid [step=1mm] +(4, 8);
\draw[help lines] (0, -4) grid [step=10mm] +(4, 8);
\filldraw (0,0) circle [radius=2pt];

\node (c1) at (0,3)
  [draw=blue, alias=last, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm, draw] {};
\fill[red!90!black] (c1.south) circle[radius=0.4pt]
  node[inner sep=0pt, below=0pt of c1.south, line width=0pt] {c1.south};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is `c1.south` precisely at the lower limit of the ink here? Because by default, `/pgf/outer sep` is half the line width. If we set `outer sep=3pt` (same as the line width) after `draw opacity=0.3` in this example, we get the following, because this starts from the *middle line* of the blue stripe whose width is the line width:

[image]

And if we use `outer sep=0pt`, `c1.south` is spot on this middle line (ordinate that is a multiple of 5). And this is enough to fix your shifting issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Coming from CSS inner and outer sep seem similar to the margin and padding

Comment: Yes, padding in CSS is similar to `inner sep` and margin to `outer sep` (the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) explicitly mentions this, see §17.2.3, *Common Options: Separations, Margins, Padding and Border Rotation*).

Answer (score 2):

Some explanation on [Peter Grill's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646895).

Suppose `\i` is `2`, then in `\node[unit] (c\i) [alias=last, below=5mm of last] {};` the resulted distance between coordinates `last.center` and `c2.center` is

radius_last + outer_sep_last + 5mm + outer_sep_c2 + radius_c2 = 15mm + .4pt

in which

- radius_last = radius_c2 = 5mm and
- outer_sep_last = outer_sep_c2 = line_width / 2 = .2pt

Here outer_sep is controlled by key [`outer sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf./pgf/outer:sep) which is initially half the line width. And the line_width is controlled by key [`line width`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/line:width) which is initially .4pt.